# Set the minDistance in geonear

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-orm, odm

I'm trying to have a geo-pagination system.
I refeer to this article 
[Blog article from mongoDB](http://emptysqua.re/blog/paging-geo-mongodb/)

 My problem is that I'm using doctrine MongoDB and i don't seem to find how to set  **minDistance** field in **Doctrine MongoDB**
My Mongo version is **2.4.8**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for this was not implemented in Doctrine MongoDB, but I've implemented it in [PR #171](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/pull/171), which is now in the `1.2.x-dev` branch (we don't yet have a 1.2.0 release). You can look at the documentation blocks or unit tests in that PR for insight into how to use it, but I modeled it after `maxDistance()`.

I should mention that in 1.1.x of Doctrine MongoDB, you didn't actually need the builder method available to inject the `minDistance` option into `geoNear`. If you look at [this code in Query.php](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/blob/1.1.5/lib/Doctrine/MongoDB/Query/Query.php#L249), you'll see that we merge options from the builder atop `$options`, which ultimately comes from Query's constructor. Keep this in mind should you need to pass options to other commands when there is not a pre-existing builder method.

Lastly, you mentioned that you're using MongoDB 2.4.8. Note that MongoDB 2.4.x does not support this option (for `geoNear`) or query operator (for `$near` and `$nearSphere`). It was implemented in [SERVER-9395](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9395) ([this commit](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/53dab689a519b4daf6a5c4772123b74616c0283b)) and first appeared in 2.5.1. You'll also find it in 2.6.0, of course.

Comment: Yes you're right ! I've just updated to Version 2.6 and I'm struggling with doctrine to make it work